# Type error on ViewModelProviders#of(Fragment)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm trying to go through the [google tutorial on building good ap architecture](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/guide.html). I'm using java 8 and SDK 26.
Here is the code I have so far :

```
package test.me;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel;
import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;

public class ChronoFragment extends Fragment {

    private ViewModel my_model;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        my_model = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ViewModel.class);  // <-- error on this
        // and so on
    }
}
```

The trouble is that so far, the SDK returns the following error:

```
Cannot resolve the method 'of(test.me.ChronoFragment)'.
```

I don't understand this since

- `ChronoFragment` is of type Fragment
- The method ViewModelProviders#of(Fragment) [does exist](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModelProviders.html#of(android.support.v4.app.Fragment)) and is accessible via the sdk.

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Architecture Components uses the appcompat `Fragment` from the support library rather than the native one. Try changing your import for `Fragment` to

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

For historical reasons, there are two different `Fragment` classes. They have the same functionality but exist in two different packages. For details, see [Why are there two Fragment classes in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48291270/why-are-there-two-fragment-classes-in-android/48291271#48291271)

**As of Feb 6, 2019:**

Now there is a third `Fragment` class. If you are using the new AndroidX libraries, then do

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
```

Be sure you use the correct `Fragment` class which is consistent with the rest of your dependencies.

Comment: @fxm You will need to be careful with the rest of your app. My suggestion is to consistently use the support `Fragment` class across the board so that you don't run into similar issues elsewhere.

Comment: I'll do so, but I admit I'm a bit confused by what looks like a duplicate to me. I'll have to read more I guess

Comment: @fxm What duplicate do you mean? Are you referring to the two `Fragment` classes?

Comment: Yes, components seems to be almost vanilla android when reading the doc and yet, there exist a somewhat different fragment class than in the original code

Comment: @fxm Hopefully [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48291270/why-are-there-two-fragment-classes-in-android/48291271#48291271) will clear up some of the confusion. The main reason for having two `Fragment` classes is historical.

Answer (score 4):

I have had the same problem, what the google documentation does not tell you is that you need to add the following dependencies in to your Build Gradle file and then "Sync"

```
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"
```

Comment: Links to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components) and [release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/release-notes)

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same problem while using Android X libraries and used following to resolved.

**Gradle dependencies for Android X:**

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0-alpha04"
annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.1.0-alpha04"`
```

**Import:**

```
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel;
```

Reference - https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem, android studio automatically imported `android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` but I was using androidX. if your situation is same, you must use
androidX imports everywhere

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
```