# Why are there two Fragment classes in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library, android-appcompat

In a [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48291104/type-error-on-viewmodelprovidersoffragment), the OP received an unexpected error message due to importing `Fragment` from the `android.app` package. The solution to fix the error was to import `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` instead. Why are there two different `Fragment` classes that appear to have the same functionality?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109017/difference-between-android-app-fragment-and-android-support-v4-app-fragment

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html), fragments were introduced in Android 3.0 (API 11). Around the same time, Google also released the Android Support Library which allowed developers to use fragments and other new APIs on devices that ran older versions of Android. This library contained classes with the exact same functionality as classes that shipped with the Android API on newer devices. Since these libraries can be compiled directly into your APK file, you no longer have to rely on the features being available on the target device. Some classes are now only available from the Support Library and rely on the support `Fragment` from this library rather than using the native `Fragment` class even though it is available on basically all devices now in use.

Comment: …and now, since February 2011… every Android developer has been, and continues to, suffer this craziness. Instead of performing the abstraction at a controlled environment (Android Code), Google decided to let users deal with it.

Comment: Long story short, just use `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. You will have to use it 99% of the time as long as you're using any other Android support libraries.